# Vagrant access Dart webdev server

Tags: dart, configuration, vagrant, port, portforwarding

I am learning Dart. I already installed Dart, and also the CLI tools (webdev and stagehand).

I successfully made a Dart console app and ran it without any issues. Then I started a bare-bones web app project and I ran the app with the following command:

```
webdev serve
```

And it started to run the web app in localhost on port 8080:

> Serving `web` on http://127.0.0.1:8080

I already changed the forwarded port to 8080 in the vagrant file like this:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
```

But I still cannot access/view the Dart web app, so my best guest is that I am doing something wrong with the port forwarding. How can I access my Dart web app running in vagrant from the browser?

I am using an ubuntu box.

Comment: Have you tried switch the port for guest and host?